# Trying to post a data to a SOAP method via PHP

Tags: php, oop, object, soap

I have a webservice based on SOAP protocole. The SOAP provides a method Add, that take an OO object variable as input.

I'm trying to Add data to their service. This is the code:

```
// this classes create a structure for WSSE security headers 
class clsWSSEAuth
{
  private $Username;
  private $Password; 
  function __construct($u, $p)
  {
    $this->Username = $u; 
    $this->Password = $p;
  }
}

class clsWSSEToken
{
  private $UsernameToken;
  function __construct($i)
  {
    $this->UsernameToken=$i; 
  }
}    

$params = array('trace' => true);

$user = 'xxxxxx'; 
$pass = base64_encode(sha1('yyyyy', true));  //sha1 is sth like mdf - it codes the pass 

$wssens = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';  //namespace

$soapVarUser = new SoapVar ($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $wssens, NULL, $wssens);
$soapVarPass = new SoapVar ($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $wssens, NULL, $wssens);

//PREPARATION OF VARIABLE FO USER AND PASS - END

//Create Object for Auth Class and pass in soap var 
$wsseAuth = new clsWSSEAuth ($soapVarUser, $soapVarPass); 

//Create SoapVar out of object of Auth class 
$soapVarAuth = new SoapVar ($wsseAuth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $wssens, 'UsernameToken', $wssens);
//Create object for Token Class 
$wsseToken = new clsWSSEToken ($soapVarAuth);
//Create SoapVar out of object of Token class 
$soapVarToken = new SoapVar ($wsseToken, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $wssens, 'UsernameToken', $wssens);
//Create SoapVar for 'Security' node 
$soapHeader = new SoapVar ($soapVarToken, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $wssens, 'Security', $wssens);

//Create header object out of security soapvar 
$header = new SoapHeader($wssens, 'Security', $soapHeader, true, 'htpp://abce.com'); 

//Create object of Soap Client
$client = new SoapClient('https://xxxxxx.support.xxxxxxx.pl:8443/webservices/LAB/LabResultsManagerEP?wsdl', $params);

//Set headers for soapclient object 
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header); 

//definition of example object

class CreateOrderResultListVO {
  public $ord;
  function CreateOrderResultListVO(){
//and some other stuff here too
    $this -> ord = $any_structure_of_objects_maching_required_fields;
  }
}

$test = new CreateOrderResultListVO(); //this is preety much any php OO object

try 
{  
  $id=$client->add($test -> ord);
} catch (Exception $e) { echo "error in add method: <pre>"; var_dump($e);echo "</pre>"; }
```

Client in Java was written, and works ok. So was Client in C#. But as far as I know I'm the first one that tries to do that in PHP.

In fact the structure of objects passed to the method Add is complicated (it matches not so small xml file), but aparently that is not the problem.

I get in var_dump error: 
entire object structure + this:

```
  ["faultstring"]=>
  string(23) "VO object can't be null"
  ["faultcode"]=>
  string(10) "env:Server"
  ["detail"]=>
  object(stdClass)#19 (1) {
    ["ErlabException"]=>
    object(stdClass)#20 (2) {
      ["code"]=>
      string(10) "WRONG_DATA"
      ["message"]=>
      string(23) "VO object can't be null"
    }
  }
```

That means (I think) that soap connection is ok (I have same one in get_data method and works ok) BUT for some reason Method Add does not do anything with date I send, like it didnt see it?

I would really apriciate any help. How do I procees with this, or at least how do I look for what is wrong?

EDIT:
I hope this help: I have instaled Fiddler in order listen what is send from my pc to internet. I have configured firefox to work with it. All I get is the content of the php  webpage that is displayed in the browser. The c# and Jave clients display nothing except xml that is generated by SOAP Add method. I'm almoust sure that php connect with SOap webserwice just fine (unless error I get is not Soap Add error but Soap serwer error), so I dont understand why Fiddler show nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody really knows? :) ok, here it is, instead of standard functon call use this:

```
  $args = array('soap_parameter_name' => $xml_objects);
  $id = $client->__soapCall('add', array('parameters' => $args));
```